# NoReverseMatch at /add_post Reverse for 'article-details' with arguments '('4', '0')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blogpost/(?P<pk>[^/]+)$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Getting this issue in my django blog project. Everything is specified neatly but I don't understand why it is crashing.

**urls.py** :

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Homeview, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView

urlpatterns = [
path('', Homeview.as_view() , name="home"),
path('blogpost/<str:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-details'),
path('add_post', AddPostView.as_view( ), name="add_posts")
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse '''


class Post(models.Model):
blog_title =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField(default="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.blog_title + '|' + str(self.author)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article-details', args = str(self.id))
```

**articledetails.html***
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{post.blog_title}}</h1>
</br>
{{post.body}}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *args* argument of reverse want an iterable value. You gave it a string. Let's assume it is "40".

So, the reverse function will get each element of the iterable and assign them to the arguments of the url (here: *pk*).

"40" being a string, its elements are its individual characters: "4" and "0".
Since your url only have one argument, you have this error.

What you should do to have a dirty fix:

```
reverse('article-details', args=[str(self.id)])
```

If you want a clean fix, your should also modify the <str:pk> of your url to <int:pk>. Your primary keys are integer, so get an integer as your views url kwargs.

Comment: That worked sir !!! Thanks a lot for your answer for helping me sir. Was trying to figure out since two days